# Can't get horizontal <UL> menu to center or be wide enough, keeps wrapping to new line

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm trying to get my webpage to look like this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm52l.jpg

I am having trouble with the horizontal menu, though. I'm not sure what I did wrong but it keeps wanting to wrap to the next line for some reason even though there is plenty of room on the current line. I'm sure I'm overlooking something or have done something completely the wrong way. I'm not very good with this sort of thing.  Here is my code, any help is appreciated.

Here's my code. I made the #menu background color orange just to try and see what was going on:

```css
#header {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu {
  background-color: orange;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
  text-align: left;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
a[href="#"]:hover {
  color: white;
  background: gray;
}
#left {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 160px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px
}
#right {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 160px;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
}
#content {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">Ball State University Education Redefined
</div>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Admissions</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Academics</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Campus Life</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Athletics</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Calendar</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Giving</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut.
</div>
<div id="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut.
</div>
<div id="content">

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
  ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue
  duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.

</div>
```

Comment: can you please explain why you use `50%` left position? If you want to center the element, try `margin: 0 auto` instead.

Comment: @Aziz that was just how another website suggested solving the issue. which selector are you saying I should put the `margin: 0 auto` in?

Comment: It would be great if you could accept an answer, if any, that solve your question, or let us know what is missing, so we can find one that does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an update of your code. Is this the layout you want?

To make it behave I removed `float: right;`, `left: -50%;` and changed to `text-align: center` on `#menu`, removed `left: 50%` and added `display: inline-block` on `ul`

I also recommend removing the float on the `li`, and either use `flex` or `display: inline-block`.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

#header {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
#menu {
  background-color: orange;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
}
ul {
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li{  
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;   
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

a[href="#"]:hover { 
  color: white;
  background: gray; 
}

#left {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 160px;   
  float: left;
  padding: 10px
}

#right {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 160px;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
}

#content {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link href="project1.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="header">Ball State University Education Redefined
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Admissions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Academics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Campus Life</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Athletics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Giving</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div id="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut. 
    </div>
    <div id="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut. 
    </div>
    <div id="content">

      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. 

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to float your centered nav bar. Also, the `left: 50%`s on both the ul and the container are unnecessary. Instead, center the containing `#menu` with `margin:0 auto` and center the `li`s with `display:inline-block` and `text-align:center`. This will allow it to stay in the document's flow, and resize more dynamically. It will now only wrap when the window gets too small.

```css
#menu {
background-color: orange;
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;

text-align:left;
}

ul {
list-style:none;
position:relative;
text-align:center;
}

ul li{  
list-style: none;
display:inline-block;
background-color: red;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 15px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ez8hy7yt/

Answer (score 1):

Like Blue_Dragon said, you can get rid of several things.  I commented out some code in your CSS that you don't need. There may be more. Also, consider adjusting the ul to inline-block and text-align center the #menu, to get rid of the spaces between each list item - https://jsfiddle.net/shwL0wr1/

```
#menu {
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
   display: inline-block;
}
```